# Encrypted pdf doesn't open in macOS PDFKit

Tags: macos

After the macOS 10.12.4 update encrypted pdfs don't open in PDFKit. When opening the PDF a blank view is displayed, this also happens in the Preview app.

Here is how I create the PDF document. After creating the PDFDocument I assign that document to a PDFView.

```
let bookData = NSData(contentsOfFile: filePath)
    if let bookData = bookData as? Data {
    let pdfDocument = PDFDocument(data: bookData)
    pdfDocument?.unlock(withPassword: password)
    self.pdfDocument = pdfDocument
}
```

The problem is that some PDFs open and others don't but all the PDFs open in Adobe Reader

Comment: Apple "revised" PDFKit in Sierra, and lots of bugs were introduced in the process. These have been mostly fixed now (by Mojave 10.14).